# Group Elements after unwind and ignore duplication - MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I use aggregation to unwind an array, and group by each element of array to sum some correspondant values.

My collection is like :

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59ce411c2708c97154d1319b"),
    "sourceMediumPath" : [ 
        {
            "nodeValue" : "(direct) / (none)"
        }, 
        {
            "nodeValue" : "(direct) / (none)"
        }
    ],
    "totalConversions" : 1,
    "totalConversionValue" : 171.6,
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59ce411c2708c97154d136a0"),
    "sourceMediumPath" : [ 
        {
            "nodeValue" : "google / cpc"
        }, 
        {
            "nodeValue" : "(direct) / (none)"
        }, 
        {
            "nodeValue" : "google / cpc"
        }
    ],
    "totalConversions" : 1,
    "totalConversionValue" : 151.8,
}
```

I want to group by sourceMedium.nodeValue and sum 'totalConverions' and 'totalConversionValue' without conseidering the duplicate elements.

For example by using the unwinding, grouping, and sum :

```
aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                    Aggregation.unwind("sourceMediumPath"),
                    Aggregation.group("sourceMediumPath.nodeValue")
                            .sum("totalConversions").as(Variables.TOTAL_CONNVERSIONS)
                            .sum("TotalConversionValue").as(Variables.TOTAL_CONVERSION_VALUE),

                    Aggregation.project("sourceMediumPath.nodeValue")
                            .andInclude(Variables.TOTAL_CONNVERSIONS, Variables.TOTAL_CONVERSION_VALUE)
```

I get for "nodeValue" : "(direct) / (none)" a Sum of TotalConversions equals to 3 and for "google / cpc" a Sum equals to 1. Because it duplicate totalConversions and totalConversions while doing the unwind operation.

There is any solution to ignore the duplication and have just one value per document.

how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spring Data the intersectarrays in Aggregation projection pipeline did the job, By applying the intesection with same the array.

```
aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
               Aggregation.project().and("sourceMediumPathnodeValue").intersectsArrays("sourceMediumPathnodeValue").as("Intersection").andInclude(...),
                    Aggregation.unwind("Intersection"),
                    Aggregation.group("Intersection")
                            .sum("totalConversions").as("totalConversions")
                            .sum("TotalConversionValue").as(TotalConversionValue"),
                    Aggregation.project("sourceMediumPath.nodeValue")
                            .andInclude("totalConversions", TotalConversionValue")

                        new OutOperation("OutputCollection")
                ).withOptions(Aggregation.newAggregationOptions().allowDiskUse(true).build());
```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can prepend `$unwind` stage with [$addField](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) to create an array of unique values using [$setIntersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/#exp._S_setIntersection) and unwind this field as folowing:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
    { $addFields: {
        sourceMediumUniquePath: { $setIntersection: [ 
            "$sourceMediumPath", 
            "$sourceMediumPath" 
        ] }
    } },
    { $unwind: "$sourceMediumUniquePath" },
    ... rest of the pipeline ...
])
```

**Update:**

If `$addFields` is not supported, it can be replaced with `$project` stage. The only disadvantage is that you will need to list all fields you will need at later stages. E.g.:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
    { $project: {
        sourceMediumUniquePath: { $setIntersection: [ 
            "$sourceMediumPath", 
            "$sourceMediumPath" 
        ] },
        totalConversions: 1,
        totalConversionValue: 1
    } },
    { $unwind: "$sourceMediumUniquePath" },
    ... rest of the pipeline ...
])
```

Comment: Thank you so much I thought about that but I didn't get this as technique. I'm a new player in Mongodb aggregations, do you how how perform it with Java pipeline, I can't find $addFields pipeline in the aggregations

Comment: Please see the update without `$addField` stage. I don't have much experience with spring, but it  seems you can add fields in projection stage: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation.projection Must be something like `and("sourceMediumPath").intersects("sourceMediumPath").as("sourceMediumUniquePath")`

Comment: Yes Indeed ! Thank you so much there projection in spring data support Intersection : Aggregation.project(X,Y,Z).and(sourceMediumPath).intersectsArrays(sourceMediumPath).as("Intersect") .. I will post the solution once it work .. Thank you for you help